# Find the co-ordinates of the point on the curve

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, gradient-flows

Calculate the points on the curve $y=(1-x)^4$ at gradient = -4

I solve little bit

$\frac{dy}{dx} = 4(1-x)^{4-1}\cdot \frac{d}{dx} (1-x)\\
      = 4(1-x)^3 \cdot (-1 )$

the gradient is =-4 so I put it in the equation

$-4 = -4(1-x)^3$

what i should do next

Comment: Divide by -4, take the cube root and you have $1 = 1-x$ or $x=0$.  Put this value back into the original equation to get $y=1$.

Comment: @PaulSundheim thanks.. your answer is correct !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parametric form of the curve is $[t,(1-t)^4]$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}_{(\text{at }x=t)}=-4(1-t)^3$$

So, we need $-4(1-t)^3=-4$

Solve for $t$

Can you take it from here?